# Colors in Exam class?

Tags: color, exam

I would like to configure the colours in the Exam class, but it is not working and I get no colours.

```
\documentclass[french,a4paper,addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{FillWithLinesColor}{HTML}{00F9DE}
\definecolor{FillWithDottedLinesColor}{gray}{0.8}
\colorlet{GridColor}{Cerulean}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
    \question[10]
    Foo?

    \fillwithlines{2cm}

    \question[15]
    Bar?

    \fillwithdottedlines{2cm}

    \question[10] Compute $\displaystyle\int_0^1 x^2 \, dx$.

    \fillwithgrid{2cm}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify that you want colours for the lines/dots/grids via

```
\colorfillwithlines
\colorfillwithdottedlines
\colorgrids
```

These commands each sets a conditional flag and also define the associated colours (`FillWithLinesColor`, `FillWithDottedLinesColor` and `GridColor`) with the defaults. Only after that you should (re)define the colours. Using your approach the colours are overwritten by the defaults, hence no change in the (colour of the) output.

[image]

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\colorfillwithlines
\colorfillwithdottedlines
\colorgrids

\colorlet{FillWithLinesColor}{red}%\definecolor{FillWithLinesColor}{HTML}{00F9DE}
\colorlet{FillWithDottedLinesColor}{green}%\definecolor{FillWithDottedLinesColor}{gray}{0.8}
\colorlet{GridColor}{blue}%\colorlet{GridColor}{Cerulean}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \question[10]
  Foo?

  \fillwithlines{2cm}

  \question[15]
  Bar?

  \fillwithdottedlines{2cm}

  \question[10] Compute $\displaystyle\int_0^1 x^2 \, dx$.

  \fillwithgrid{2cm}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```